# How can I trigger a download with typo3/extbase?

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, fluid

I'm using Typo3 with extbase and fluid. I have a Controller with an action called `downloadAction()`. After calling the action the system tries to render the download-template (but I just want to start a download).

```
public function downloadAction($id) {
  // create file
  // send header
  // dump file
  // exit
}
```

How can I dump the created `download-File` and send a download header instead of the normal render process? What is the best way?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I did this in a project some months ago, it's pretty straight forward.

```
    /**
     * @param string $fileName
     * @return void
     */  
    public function downloadAction($fileName) {

        $file = $this->settings['uploadFolder'] . 'uploadedPhotos/' . $fileName;        

        if(is_file($file)) {

            $fileLen    = filesize($file);          
            $ext        = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fileName, '.'), 1));

            switch($ext) {
                case 'txt':
                    $cType = 'text/plain'; 
                break;              
                case 'pdf':
                    $cType = 'application/pdf'; 
                break;
                case 'zip':
                    $cType = 'application/zip';
                break;
                case 'doc':
                    $cType = 'application/msword';
                break;
                case 'xls':
                    $cType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
                break;
                case 'ppt':
                    $cType = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint';
                break;
                case 'gif':
                    $cType = 'image/gif';
                break;
                case 'png':
                    $cType = 'image/png';
                break;
                case 'jpeg':
                case 'jpg':
                    $cType = 'image/jpg';
                break;
                case 'mp3':
                    $cType = 'audio/mpeg';
                break;
                case 'wav':
                    $cType = 'audio/x-wav';
                break;
                case 'mpeg':
                case 'mpg':
                case 'mpe':
                    $cType = 'video/mpeg';
                break;
                case 'mov':
                    $cType = 'video/quicktime';
                break;
                case 'avi':
                    $cType = 'video/x-msvideo';
                break;

                //forbidden filetypes
                case 'inc':
                case 'conf':
                case 'sql':                 
                case 'cgi':
                case 'htaccess':
                case 'php':
                case 'php3':
                case 'php4':                        
                case 'php5':
                exit;

                case 'exe':                 
                default:
                    $cType = 'application/octet-stream';
                break;
            }

            $headers = array(
                'Pragma'                    => 'public', 
                'Expires'                   => 0, 
                'Cache-Control'             => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',                    
                'Content-Description'       => 'File Transfer',
                'Content-Type'              => $cType,
                'Content-Disposition'       => 'attachment; filename="'. $fileName .'"',
                'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary', 
                'Content-Length'            => $fileLen         
            );

            foreach($headers as $header => $data)
                $this->response->setHeader($header, $data); 

            $this->response->sendHeaders();                 
            @readfile($file);   

        }   
        exit;   
    }
```

Comment: ASAIK, there is no `application/force-download`, it is an unrecognized MIME type and falls back to `application/octet-stream`, which would the proper MIME type to use.

Answer (score 5):

You can define a special PageType for download requests:

```
download = PAGE
download  {
  typeNum = 1249058993
  10 < tt_content.list.20.efempty_pi1

  config {
   disableAllHeaderCode = 1
   xhtml_cleaning = 0
   admPanel = 0
   additionalHeaders = Content-type:application/octet-stream
    }
  }
}
```

"efempty" must be replaced by your extension's name.

You are now able to trigger the download like this:

```
<f:link.action pageType="1249058993" action="download" controller="ControllerName">Download</f:link.action>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:
This actually doesn't work with activated compression because the Content-Length will still represent the uncompressed size. eID could be used as workaround in fact there is even a official call for that:

eID = "dumpFile" see typo3/sysext/core/Resource/PHP/FileDumpEID.php

However this call won't force a download but instead "dump" it. I've made a ticket @ Forge to fix this (which was accepted and is targeted for LTS 7): https://forge.typo3.org/issues/67111

**Old answer**:
As for now the easiest way to accomplish this is:

### TypoScript Constants

```
# ASCII "download" in Numbers (4-15-23-14-12-15-1-4) - See http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/numbers.php
plugin.tx_extensionname.view.formatToPageTypeMapping.download = 4152314121514
```

### TypoScript Setup

```
tx_extensionname_download = PAGE
tx_extensionname_download {
    typeNum < plugin.tx_extensionname.view.formatToPageTypeMapping.download
    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        xhtml_cleaning = 0
        admPanel = 0
        debug = 0
        no_cache = 1
    }

    10 = USER
    10 {
        userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
        extensionName = ExtensionName
        pluginName = PluginName
        vendorName = VENDOR
        controller = ControllerName
        action = download

        view < plugin.tx_extensionname.view
        persistence < plugin.tx_extensionname.persistence
        settings < plugin.tx_extensionname.settings
    }
}
```

### Controller Action

```
/**
 * Download
 *
 * @param \VENDOR\ExtensionName\Domain\Model\Model $model
 * @return void
 * @ignorevalidation $model
 */
public function downloadAction($model) {
    if ($model->getFile()) {
        $model->getFile()->getOriginalResource()->getOriginalFile()->getStorage()->dumpFileContents(
            $model->getFile()->getOriginalResource(),
            $asDownload = TRUE,
            $alternativeFilename = $model->getFile()->getOriginalResource()->getName()
        );
        exit;
    }

    $this->throwStatus(
        $statusCode = 404,
        $statusMessage = 'Not Found'
    );
}
```

### Fluid

```
<f:link.action controller="ControllerName" pluginName="PluginName" action="download" arguments="{model: '{model.uid}'}" format="download" title="{model.file.originalResource.title}">Download</f:link.action>
```

The benefits vs the other mentioned answers are as following:

- Proper headers (including mime/type)
- Extbase formats instead typenum

Side note: iPhone ignores the Content-Disposition headers (always inline)

About the "exit" concerns i've not tested it but with the page type it might work if you would use a own PHPView (StandaloneView?).

Answer (score 0):

> How can I dump the created download-File and send a download header instead of the normal render process?

As long as [headers haven't already been sent](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php), there is nothing at all stopping you from emitting your headers, sending the content and actually calling `exit`, though you might want to [check for output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-level.php) and [clear any open buffers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php) before doing so.  You might also want to [inspect the list of headers that will be sent](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php).

Comment: There must be a better way. I want to avoid the use of exit.

Comment: The only other option is `return`ing, at which point control would return to the framework, and it would continue to process the request as needed, i.e. kicking off the un-helpful helpers that would effectively interfere with the download.  A single *rude* exit is probably not going to be harmful.