# TYPO3: File download in Backend

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase

I would like to integrate a CSV download in the Backend. The CSV file doesn't have to be saved on the server, so just a simple Array-to-CSV for download.

I know using FAL is quite tedious in TYPO3 so I would like to know if there is a simple solution for my issue. Like calling a "download" action an returning a "CSV string" to download ?

I did used this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554211/how-can-i-trigger-a-download-with-typo3-extbase) for the download action but I am looking for a solution without FAL and without keeping the file on the server.

Comment: Maybe you will have a look at EXT:powermail from In2code wich includes xls/csv export of data stored in db

Comment: Have you seen that you can export any table visible in list module? just enter the table-view (e.g. clicking on table name). Then you get two buttons to download a CSV and to export the data of current table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for FAL or saving a file on the server. You can add a custom action in your controller that sets the content-type and disposition headers to treat your request like a download:

```php
public function exportAction()
{
    // Just an example on how you could access the downloadable data.
    $records = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTgetRows('*', 'tx_domain_model_table');
    // modify the result to be a csv encoded string, json or whatever you want it to be.
    $data = myConvert($records, 'csv');

    header('Content-Type: text/x-csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.csv"');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');

    return $data;
}
```

Where `$data` equals a csv encoded array for example.

What's more interesting is what kind of data you want to be downloadable. To make your data downloadable, setting the `header()`'s and returning any simple data type should work.